# How do I open a web page with a batch parameter?

Tags: batch-file, voip

my VoIP soft phone has the feature to start an application when a call comes in. I want to be able to see the details of the caller by going to a yellow-pages website.

This is what I've got so far (,batch file):

```
@echo off
echo Loading
start http://www.gevonden.cc/telefoonnummer/%CallerNumber%/lastname
```

(Telefoonnummer is Dutch for Phone Number)

The `%CallerNumber%` parameter has been provided by the Soft-Phone.

When I start the file, the webpage opens, but then goes to http://www.gevonden.cc/telefoonnummer//lastname

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It would appear that the `CallerNumber` parameter hasn't been provided as you think it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Soft-Phone program run your `bat` with the phone number as parameter you have to use `%1` to get it :

```
@echo off
echo Loading
start http://www.gevonden.cc/telefoonnummer/%1/lastname
```